# WPF: Setting Canvas color in a DataTrigger when bound value is null

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm binding the Background property of a Canvas to some **SelectedColorItem** object like this:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Canvas">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedColorItem,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}"
                                             Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                 </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Style>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding SelectedColorItem.MediaColor}" />
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

It works - it displays the selected color.
What does not work it the DataTrigger which I wrote to indicate that the **SelectedColorItem** is null.

The simplest **isNullValueConverter** works either - it might be varified with a Label:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=SelectedColorItem,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}" />
```

It shows **True**, when SelectedColorItem is null and **False** otherwise.

Could somebody tell me what's wrong with the trigger?

P.S.
SelectedColorItem is an instance of a ColorItemClass which contains a MediaColor property:

```
public System.Windows.Media.Color MediaColor {get;set;}
```

Comment: I think it will be easier for us to answer if you'll provide little more clarification about your questions. I mean, if you'll share any sample code of your application then.

Comment: I added the description of the property that relates to the question, but there's nothing wrong with the code at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is that the value set on the element itself has higher "priority" when values from the style, meaning that values set inside the style (including triggers) cannot override locally set values.

That being set, you need to have both values on the same level, so just move the `Background` property binding inside the style:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Canvas">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding SelectedColorItem.MediaColor}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedColorItem,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource isNullConverter}}"
                                             Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                 </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Style>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You explicitly set the Background property. now the easiest way to achieve what you want is to set the bindings fallbackvalue to Red. Like:

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding SelectedColorItem.MediaColor, FallbackValue=Red}" />
    </Canvas.Background>
</Canvas>
```

or you could also use the same datatrigger with the value false to set the binding

Comment: Thank you, Markus. The code snippet you wrote works as well as your suggestion to use another datatrigger.